# Dealing with indicator functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I am calculating the integral of two [indicator functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) with Mathematica. I'm having difficulty in imposing assumptions. What I have done so far:

To define an indicator function:

```
indicator[c_,d_][x_]:= Piecewise[{{1,c<=x <= d},{0, True}}];
```

Then the integral is:

```
Integrate[indicator[-1,1][x-y]*indicator[-n,n][y], {y,-Infinity, Infinity},Assumptions->{Element[n,Integers]}]
```

Now what I expected, was that it gives me the length of intersection between the two segments $[-n,n]$ and $[x-1,x+1]$, but it lists a set of cases for different values of n and x, but it is still assuming n is real, because it considers cases such as $0<n<1$. Any suggestions?

Comment: You know that `Boole[]` is built-in, no?

Comment: @J.M. no :( but do you think the issue stems from my definition of "indicator" above?

Comment: Use `UnitBox` or `HeavisidePi`, properly scaled.

Answer (score 3):

```
FullSimplify@Assuming[n > 0, 
 Integrate[
  UnitBox[2 (x - y)] UnitBox[n y], 
  {y, -\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]}]]
```

$\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{2} & (n>0\land 4 n x+2>n\land 4 n x+n\leq 2)\lor (n=2\land x=0) \\
 \frac{1}{n} & n>2\land 4 n x+n\geq 2\land 4 n x+2\leq n \\
 \frac{1}{2}-x & n=2\land 0<x<\frac{1}{2} \\
 x+\frac{1}{2} & n=2\land -\frac{1}{2}<x<0 \\
 \frac{-4 n x+n+2}{4 n} & 4 n x<n+2\land ((n>2\land 4 n x+2>n)\lor (4 n x+n>2\land n<2))
   \\
 \frac{1}{2 n}+x+\frac{1}{4} & 4 n x+n+2>0\land ((n>2\land 4 n x+n<2)\lor (n<2\land 4 n
   x+2\leq n))
\end{cases}$

Comment: Clearly, then:  `UnitBox[2 n y]`.  I'll let you figure out the cases with non-zero centers, etc.

Comment: Try PiecewiseExpand[UnitBox[2ny]] ... This is -1/(4n)<=y<=1/(4n)